# Windows Live SDK doesn't LogOut()

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-live-id

Microsoft Live ID is now called Microsoft Account. Having said that, let's say I log into Windows 8 as `sam@email.com` and run an app.

That app uses the Live SDK to access my Microsoft Account profile. Before it can do so, however, I must give it explicit permission and log in. So far, perfect.

Though I gave the app permission to `sam@email.com` I want to change it to `janet@email.com` so I click the app's <kbd>Logout</kbd> button which queries `LiveAuthClient.CanLogout()` from the SDK. Confusingly, the SDK returns false (I cannot log out).

**Why not?** Once the current Windows 8 user has logged into a Windows 8 app using the Windows Live SDK, how can they log out (when CanLogOut() always returns false)? Is there a setting or something to allow this?

> Turns out that this question's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294496/can-the-windows-8-live-sdk-use-another-microsoft-account-other-than-the-current) is inaccurate.

Comment: I agree that this is a good question - how can I clear my app's session cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your scope.
if you use `wl.signin`, you cannot log out via code anymore because it's single sign in. Try to use `wl.basic` instead. More about scopes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243646.aspx). When you accidently used the `wl.signin` you have to log in your dashboard an remove the app connection by hand.

Comment: Could you offer a tip about how to remove the connection by hand?  I went to the Live dashboard, but could not find any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

this is the expected behaviour. Please take a look at the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-PT/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh968445.aspx#signout).

If the user signs in to Windows 8 with a Microsoft account or a local or domain account that is connected to a Microsoft account, providing a custom sign-out button has no effect. So the only way to have a user connect to apps with different Microsoft Accounts is if the user has not associated his Microsoft Account with Windows 8.

Hope this helps...

Comment: You may be right. But because the store allows users to log out and log in as different Microsoft Accounts, it seems this is not a technical impossibility. Perhaps it just is with the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use "wl.signin" in your scopes. If you have been testing your app with this in, go into your account preferences for your live account and remove this option from the app's access. This will now allow more than one user to sign in.

```
    private LiveAuthClient authClient;

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.authClient = new LiveAuthClient("yourclientidhere");
}
then you can call this.authClient.Logout(); when you want to change users.
```