# How can I get a UX similar to the Windows Store app for Live account login when the user has a linked Windows/Microsoft account?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I’m working on getting data sync happening for my Win8/WP8 app - written in **XAML/C#**. Periodically / or at app start up / suspend, I want to sync data files with the user’s OneDrive. To do that I need to get them to login to their Microsoft Live Account. I was looking to use Live SDK (v5.6) to do that.

**Problem**:

For users who have local Windows 8 accounts, the Live SDK lets me sign then in with a built-in credential prompt. This is working.

For users who have linked their Microsoft account with their Windows 8 account (and are logged in to Windows using their Microsoft account) the Live SDK lets me use single sign-on - and I have this working.

But I can’t call sign out, in order to sign in with a different Microsoft account.

**1b** is my problem. The built-in Windows Store app, lets users have a UX where they can use the MS account linked to their Windows account - OR - choose to use  a different MS account. In effect: a ‘sign in as different user’ option. (See attached). It doesn’t look like it is technically single-sign-on in the built-in Windows store app, but that’s the UX I want - I don’t care so much for single sign-on, its a nice to have, but sign-in as a different user is a very important requirement.

**What I’ve tried:**

- Lots of searching around. Found a bunch of people on the interwebs asking for the same thing. There are unanswered questions and even some ‘accepted’ answers on SO that don’t really work:

  - [Sign in to multiple Microsoft account in Windows Store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863819/sign-in-to-multiple-microsoft-account-in-windows-store-app)
  - [Windows Live SDK doesn't LogOut()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491783/windows-live-sdk-doesnt-logout)
    (incorrect answer)
  - [Can the Windows 8 Live SDK use another Microsoft Account other than the current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294496/can-the-windows-8-live-sdk-use-another-microsoft-account-other-than-the-current) (incorrect answer)
- I’ve forked the LiveSDK on Github (https://github.com/krishna-nadiminti/LiveSDK-for-Windows/commit/2cdb5408c0d8482c026cd96da6b99e4633677081) and tested it out - with and without requesting the ‘wl.signin’ scope - no good. It doesn’t have an option to change user.
- Looked through the docs for WinRT - OnlineIdAuthenticator class, there is an option to always show CredentialPrompt when signing in users - but it does not allow the user to change the username if signed in via a linked account.
- I looked through the built-in WinStore app’s js code and it uses some internal (native?) call to a ‘OMStub’ - which has methods to auth the user. This doesn’t seem to be part of the public JavaScript Live SDK

**Question(s):**

- Are there Win32 / WinRT APIs that I could use to show credential prompts in a XAML app?
- Can I use a WebView and auth users that way?
- Should I just fall back to using the REST API and roll my own auth flow + UI for this?

How does the WinStore app do it?

**Workarounds / Store certification:**

For now, I’m a bit worried I only have the last option: roll my own .NET client over the Live connect REST API, and add my own UI for the credential prompt, and a user consent dialog which look exactly like the ones that the Windows Runtime provides. What will happen to store certification in that case? I can run it past WACK first - but the store app cert guidelines don’t talk about this: so unsure whether it will pass certification.

There is no mention of Microsoft account that I could find in the app certification guidelines.

The docs for Live SDK on MSDN explicitly mention that we’re not meant to create our own login UI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh968445.aspx

However, the store app seems to violate this - may be because it doesn’t use the Live SDK at all.

There is also a MSDN article that says when the user signs in to Windows with a Microsoft account, sign out is just not possible from inside an app: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj193591.aspx#adding_user-authentication_functionality_to_your_windows_store_apps and that the only way is for the user to dissociate the Windows/Microsoft account or switch to a different user account.

Again - clearly this is not the case. The store app provides users a way to use a different account.

Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the Web Authentication Broker: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn448945.aspx

It will invoke the actual Microsoft Account login flow but still give you the flexibility to sign out and back in as another user.

Comment: It looks like that article linked here is for WinJS apps. I've updated my question to mention I'm using XAML/C#.

Comment: Also, I've checked the WebAuthenticationBroker samples in C# - it seems to be only for non-MS OAuth providers. For the Live account, the classes in the Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId namespace or the Live SDK seem to be the way to do it - which ofcourse brings me back to the original problem described in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I did link to the incorrect version of the documentation.  Here's the one I meant to post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn448945.aspx

The code samples are for non-MS OAuth, but MS OAuth is still supported by the MSA team through this flow.  All you really need are the start and end URLs, which you can find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631818.aspx

Comment: Sounds good - will try it out. Wondering if the store certification will be affected. One of the comments in the code samples for the WebAuth broker in C#, from a Microsoft person says that the Live SDK is the recommended way (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122/view/Discussions#content, by Jeremy_Viegas, bottom of the first page of Q/A).